# Is it possible to substitute an array for a range in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I've looked for a while, but haven't been able to find something that fully answers my question in a way that I can utilize for my situation.

To sum up my formula without filling my post with it, I have two columns: A "sorting/parsing" column that grabs a sorted, unique, distinct list of items, and one that makes a temporary string that pulls the primary sorting sub-string from the middle of the source data entries and appends it to the front with the concat formula.

My issue:

The source data is exported from another program that overwrites that entire sheet. My summary page that houses the above columns is unaffected by this export. However, the number of rows in the source data are dynamic, and thus I cannot adequately predict the number of rows in the helper column I need to fill out, and to fill out the entire column creates a HUGE amount of calculation overhead that I want to avoid. So the only solution I can think of is to merge the helper column into the "sorting/parsing" column, something I've done already with the sorting column (I originally had 2 helper columns, but reduced it due to space constraints). I have the "helper formula" properly converted from the helper column and ready to go, except I have a couple `COUNTIF(range,criteria)` formulas in the sorting column that don't seem to accept the array output of my helper formula as the range parameter. At least, when replacing the range of my helper column with the helper formula is what breaks the sorting formula.

Is it possible to substitute an array for a range in such a formula? I have already confirmed that the helper formula correctly produces an array version of the helper column that works in other formulas, so getting it to work as the range parameter is the last step. I would prefer to stay away from VBA for this if I can, as my document will act as a template for others to copy into different project drives and I wish to avoid any issues/questions/worries that may arise from a script enabled file being automated into those same drives. I understand if VBA is the only solution, and can write a script if need be.

If the array should work properly in the range parameter, what could be holding it up? If I do `COUNTIF(helper_column,">"&helper_formula)`, it works, but `COUNTIF(helper_formula,">"&helper_formula)` does not.

I can bypass this entire issue by just referencing the source data instead of the helper column, but then I risk the ordering {1, 10, 2, 3, 4, ...} instead of {1, 2, 3, 4, 10, ...} should a 10" be present in the source data.

Formula Info:

Source data contains a number followed by a quotation (") somewhere in the string (e.i. Test A - 1").

Helper column (column N) contains:
  `=IF(I2<>"",CONCATENATE(RIGHT(CONCATENATE(0,VALUE(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",MID(I2,SEARCH("""",I2)-2,2)),0)>0,MID(I2,SEARCH("""",I2)-1,1),MID(I2,SEARCH("""",I2)-2,2)))),2)&" "&I2),"")`

Helper array formula (replaces column N references in sorting formula):
   `=IF($I$2:$I$27<>"",CONCATENATE(RIGHT(CONCATENATE(0,VALUE(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",MID($I$2:$I$27,SEARCH("""",$I$2:$I$27)-2,2)),0)>0,MID($I$2:$I$27,SEARCH("""",$I$2:$I$27)-1,1),MID($I$2:$I$27,SEARCH("""",$I$2:$I$27)-2,2)))),2)&" "&$I$2:$I$27),"")`

Sorting formula:
`=IFERROR(RIGHT(INDEX($N$2:$N$27, MATCH(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($V$1:V1,RIGHT($N$2:$N$27,LEN($N$2:$N$27)-3))=0, COUNTIF($N$2:$N$27, "<"&$N$2:$N$27), ""), 1), COUNTIF($N$2:$N$27, "<"&$N$2:$N$27), 0)),LEN(INDEX($N$2:$N$27, MATCH(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($V$1:V1,RIGHT($N$2:$N$27,LEN($N$2:$N$27)-3))=0, COUNTIF($N$2:$N$27, "<"&$N$2:$N$27), ""), 1), COUNTIF($N$2:$N$27, "<"&$N$2:$N$27), 0)))-3),"")`

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, and let me know if I need to include any additional information to resolve this.

EDIT:
As requested, example data set with expected output:

Example Source Data. This is what I have been working with in my working/test file.

[image: Example Source Data. This is what I have been working with in my working/test file]

Example Output. This is the currently working sorting formula when referencing the helper column.

[image: Example Output. This is the currently working sorting formula when referencing the helper column.]

Comment: Countif is one of the formulas that cannot take an array in the first criterion.  It must be an array.

Comment: Any chance you can mock up a small example of what you are trying to do with data and expected output?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Is there another way to accomplish this without needing a helper column the full row-length of the source data?
I've updated the post to include snippets of example source data and desired output.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to control where the <number"> notation lands in each entry of the source data.

Comment: It will take, vba, fixing the source data to use 2 or 3 digit numbers, or helper columns.  A one stop formula is unwise and unwieldy.

Comment: I typically do use helper columns, such as how I currently have it set up, but the only way that would work in this instance is for it to be the full length of the source data, which is variable. As others will eventually be outputting to this, I can't assume that the source data could always be correctly adjusted to bring the primary sorting characters to the front due to naming conventions in the software the export is coming from. If VBA is the only other way, I'll go that route instead.

Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: Instead of formulas, why not use the Advanced Filter to copy the unique entries, and then sort them.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the Advanced Filter does not update the target field/range automatically as the source data is updated, and the summary table would need to be updated manually with the Advanced Filter every time the source data is re-exported from the original software.